# Accounting for timezone in postgres query

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp

In am trying to automatically account for timezone in my postgres query.  My goal is to select records that are between 0:00 and 23:59 in EST or UTC - 5:00.

The current query only returns records between 0:00 and 23:59 in UTC time.

```
select path, start_time from routes where routes.network_id = 1 and routes.start_time between '2017-06-13 00:00:00'::timestamp AND '2017-06-13 23:59:59'::timestamp
```

the column `start_time` is a timestamp without timezone, so by default it is in UTC

```
SELECT pg_typeof("start_time") from routes limit 1;
```

returns  `timestamp without timezone`

how would one write a query to account for 5 hours difference and convert `start_time` to UTC - 5?

Comment: this is in postgres

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select path, start_time - interval '5 hours' as start_time_est
  from routes
 where routes.network_id = 1 
       and routes.start_time between '2017-06-13 00:00:00-5'::timestamp  with time zone 
           AND '2017-06-13 23:59:59-5'::timestamp with time zone;
```